# YOLO V5 Dataset Customize with Coco dataset 2017

Tags: yolo

I want to use the processed coco dataset and custom dataset together.

I will use cars, motorcycles, and bicycles in Coco Dataset.
And I will add the electrical scooter as a new custom dataset.

Finally, we will produce the yolo v5, which object detection of cars, motorcycles, bicycles, and electric scooters.

How shall I do it?
Please let me know if there is a case.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do in order to train on both datasets is the following:

0. Create the datasets. Notice that the extracted COCO classes should get class numbers [0, 1, 2] and the scooter class you want to add should get class [3]. Notice that this numbering will affect the order of the class names in the next point. Notice as well that you can keep the subdatsets in separate folders and that you don't need to mix them into the same folder.
1. Create a `custom.yaml` file under `yolov5/data` where you specify both datasets to train and evaluate on. An example:

```yaml
# Example usage: python train.py --data custom.yaml
# parent
# ├── yolov5
# └── datasets
#     ├── coco2017_train_cars_motorcycles_bicycles
#     └── custom_train_scooters


# Train/val/test sets as 1) dir: path/to/imgs, 2) file: path/to/imgs.txt, or 3) list: [path/to/imgs1, path/to/imgs2, ..]
path: ../datasets  # dataset root dir
train: # train images (relative to 'path')
  - coco2017_train_cars_motorcycles_bicycles/images
  - custom_train_scooters/images
val:   # val images (relative to 'path')
  - coco2017_val_cars_motorcycles_bicycles/images
  - custom_val_scooters/images

#       test: # test images (optional)
#         - coco2017_test_cars_motorcycles_bicycles/images
#         - custom_test_scooters/images


# Classes
nc: 4  # number of classes
names: [ 'car', 'motorcycle', 'bicycle', 'scooter' ]  # class names
```

2. Train with this dataset configuration by:

```bash
python train.py --data custom.yaml --cfg yolov5m.yaml --weights yolov5m.pt --batch-size 16 --device 0,1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

For object detection in yolov, you need the image dataset + annotation. In the case of lack of annotation, you need to annotate manually with dome annotation tools like Roboflow or Cvat. In your case you just try to download the coco dataset and annotation from this [link](https://cocodataset.org/#download). Then annotate the custom data that you have and merge those data with corresponding directory.

For training yolov5, You can go with this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/roboflow-ai/yolov5-custom-training-tutorial/blob/main/yolov5-custom-training.ipynb) and for inference check this out [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/tutorial.ipynb#scrollTo=4JnkELT0cIJg).

For better detection, you should increase data with annotation for training and also the data that you choosing should be suits for you inference environment.